# Swift playing Videos From Local Path

Tags: swift

I'm Trying to play a video that i downloaded to the device using a Download Manager

this is the video path :

> "/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/CFFBEE5C-0AFD-40BB-A66C-7879879CFAA0/Documents/MyDownloads/Arrow.S05E01.mp4"

Im using this code to play the video :

```
let player = AVPlayer(url: URL(fileURLWithPath: path))
    let playerController = AVPlayerViewController()
    playerController.player = player
    present(playerController, animated: true) {
        player.play()
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do not use a literal string path. Get the current `Documents` folder with `FileManager`:

```
let documentsFolder = try! FileManager.default.url(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: false)
let videoURL = documentsFolder.appendingPathComponent("MyDownloads/Arrow.S05E01.mp4")
let player = AVPlayer(url: videoURL)
...
```

Comment: My video on my local server and I want to play it on my device.